# Which mysql strategy is better ? 3* (DB lookup on <=N elements) OR (DB lookup on <=3N elements)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have information which contains the following components

```
RecID
UID
Name
Namevariant1
Namevariant2
```

The NameVariant can be thought of as name aliases - for example, "John Paul" could be referred to as "JP", so if JP's information is sought, then I should be able to match JP with John Paul.

Naturally, I would like to see if my input name falls into any of these variants (including the exact match).

I see two ways of doing this:

a) Have table with Name, NameVariant1, NameVariant2 as columns. The lookup will be the following query:

```
select * from <table> where Name=<input> OR NameVariant1=<input> OR NameVariant2=<input>
```

For speed, I might want to create indexes on Name, NameVariant1, NameVariant2.

b) Have Separate table which will contain a map of the variants, and the records associated with these aliases (captured as a recordset, with a suitable delimiter):

```
RecID
UID
Name


Variant
RecordSet
```

By going with plan (b), we can avoid storing duplicate aliases. For example, "John Peter" and "John Paul" have the same alias "JP", so I do not have to store "JP" twice.

Please note that there are huge number of inputs expected on these tables, in the order of a few million records.

With respect to lookup performance, I am confused: Assuming that there are 'N' records, plan (a) lookup amounts to searching in 3 different columns - that translates to 3 * (DB lookup on <=N elements). For plan (b), lookup amounts to searching along a maximum of 3N rows [If all aliases are different from each other, there will be 3 aliases per record, and hence 3N records in the second table]. So the complexity in plan (b) is (DB lookup on <=3N elements).

**So, the question: Which strategy is better ? 3* (DB lookup on <=N elements) OR (DB lookup on <=3N elements)**

For practical purposes, one can assume that there will be very less amount of duplicate entries, so the total number of distinct aliases will be close to 3N.